# ORDER BY an aggregated column in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server

On a report builder 3.0, i retreived some items and counted them using a Count aggregate. Now i want to order them from highest to lowest. How do i use the ORDER BY function on the aggregated column? The picture below show the a column that i want to ORDER BY it, it is ticked.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vRmp.jpg)

The code is vers simple as shown bellow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT act_id,NameOfAct,
FROM Acts
```

Comment: can you provide any query what you have tried so far ?

Comment: update your question and add  your query code ..

Comment: i did so, please check

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Pic. So you might have duplicate acts with the same name. And you want to know the number of acts that have the same unique name.

You might want to group the results by name:

```
GROUP BY NameOfAct
```

And include the act names and their counts in the query results:

```
SELECT NameOfAct, COUNT(*) AS ActCount
```

(Since the act_id column is not included in the groups, you need to omit it in the SELECT. The DISTINCT is also not necessary anymore, since all groups are unique already.)

Finally, you can sort the data (probably descending to get the acts with the largest count on top):

```
ORDER BY ActCount DESC
```

Your complete query would become something like this:

```
SELECT NameOfAct, COUNT(*) AS ActCount
FROM Acts
GROUP BY NameOfAct
ORDER BY ActCount DESC
```

Edit:

By the way, you use field "act_id" in your SELECT clause. That's somewhat confusing. If you want to know counts, you want to look at either the complete table data or group the table data into smaller groups (with the GROUP BY clause). Then you can use aggregate functions to get more information about those groups (or the whole table), like counts, average values, minima, maxima...

Single record information, like an act's ID in your case, is typically not important if you want to use statistic/aggregate methods on grouped data. Suppose your query returns an act name which is used 10 times. Then you have 10 records in your table, each with a unique act_id, but with the same name.

If you need just one act_id that represents each group / act name (and assuming act_id is an autonumbering field), you might include the latest / largest act_id value in the query using the MAX aggregate function:

```
SELECT NameOfAct, COUNT(*) AS ActCount, MAX(act_id) AS LatestActId
```

(The rest of the query remains the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Your picture indicates you also want a `Total` row at the bottom:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(NameOfAct,'Total') NameOfAct,
  COUNT(DISTINCT act_id) c
FROM Acts
GROUP BY ROLLUP(NameOfAct)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN NameOfAct is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    c DESC;
```

Result of example data:

```
NameOfAct   count
--------------  -------
Act_B           3
Act_A           2
Act_Z           1
Total           6
```

Try it with example rows at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dbd6c/2

Comment: Yes. A rollup is great if you also want the complete total in the query results. Didn't include it in my answer, however, because I was not sure if his reporting engine will already calculate the complete total. (In that case, Rabelani Netshifhire's report might show a grand total that's twice the actual grand total, since it will assume that act "Total" is used a huge amount of times...)